# Error 401 al intentar hacer put con la API DE WORDPRESS (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, woocommerce

Estoy intentando actualizar el stock de los productos, pero obtengo un error 401 el cual tengo entendido es un error de acceso denegado a pesar de que tengo las claves de lectura y escritura, además e probado incluso a crear unas claves de solo escritura pero todo sigue igual.

Consola:

> request.js:149 OPTIONS
>   http://localhost/wp2/wp-json/wc/v1/products/208?oauth_consumer_key=ck_ba424e8f050f936b95eb99385de91556efae99d7&oauth_nonce=HiO8gmbAOrwmltdOupwjUvPUjbHMu5Kc&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1557994255&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=qtjHcLtq%2BT0LM95Q%2F8CScvTXEewUaNv3aBYsRXn6VcA%3D 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

Código:

```
add_stock(){
    const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
        url: 'http://localhost/wp2/',
        consumerKey: 'ck_ba424e8f050f936b95eb99385de91556efae99d7',
        consumerSecret: 'cs_a56f560259254aff907c85832126717a24231295',
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v1'
      });


       let prods = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('carrito'));
       prods.forEach((element, index) => {

        let prod = element[0];
        console.log(prod.stock_quantity);
        let data = { stock_quantity: prod.stock_quantity += 1};
        WooCommerce.put(('products/' + prod.id) , data, function(err, data, res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Los errores de CORS suelen ser un problema de bloqueo por parte del servidor, ¿qué servidor estás utilizando?

Comment: @David utilizo xampp con servidor apache